# Jenkins ver. 2.121.3 - Delete file from workspace

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins ver. 2.121.3 using pipeline trying to delete the file. Its giving script not permitted error message.

Is there a alternate way to delete the file in Jenkins with-out using OS command?

```
Scripts not permitted to use method java.io.File delete. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.io.File delete
```

**Pipeline code**

```
stage('Delete test.zip file') {
    if (fileExists('test.zip')) {
        new File('test.zip').delete()
    } else {
        println "test.zip file not found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you are not happy with `sh 'rm test.zip'` or `bat 'del test.zip'`?

Comment: Yes, Is they Jenkins way of removing the file? with sh or bat we need to check the os and call the correct command. trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to /scriptApproval/  (Manage Jenkins > In-process Script Approval) and approve the script.

Comment: File.delete works on master. So, approval makes sense only if pipeline is executed there.

Answer (score 12):

There are several alternative ways:

1. By means of [jenkins shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) you can wrap this code up to function or class:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
package org.utils

class PipelineUtils { 
    static def deleteFile(String name) { new File(name).delete() } 
}
```

in your pipeline script, you need to import the library:

```
@Library('your-jenkins-library')_    
import static org.utils.PipelineUtils.*
deleteFile('test.zip')
```

2. As @Sean has suggested to approve the script via "Manage Jenkins > In-process Script Approval".
3. There is [File Operations Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/):

```
fileOperations([script.fileDeleteOperation(excludes: '', includes: 'test.zip')])
```

4. There is [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/), but you need to find suitable exclude-patterns, otherwise this will clean all files:

```
def new_exclude_patterns = [[pattern: ".git/**", type: 'EXCLUDE']]
cleanWs deleteDirs: false, skipWhenFailed: false, patterns: new_exclude_patterns
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running pipeline on linux slave (or windows slave with sh in path), you may use the below call to avoid interactive prompts.

```
sh(""" rm -rf "$directory" """)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way since Java 1.7/Groovy ?.? is:

[`Files.delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path))([`Path.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...))`(`[`FQFN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FQN#Filenames_and_paths)`))`